# Android Camera Parameters setJpegQuality deprecated? Custom camera application

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-version

I'm building a custom camera application for Android. The [Camera.Parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html) API contains methods like `setPreviewSize` or `setPictureSize`, that are working well.

But I am trying to use [setJpegQuality(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setJpegQuality(int)) parameter:

```
    Camera cam = getCameraInstance();
    if(cam == null){
        setResult(INSTANCE_ERROR);
        finish();
    }

    params = cam.getParameters();
    params.setJpegQuality(jpegQuality); 
    cam.setParameters(params);
```

I am testing my application on 3 different devices : an HTC Desire Z, a Galaxy S2 and a Galaxy S4.

`setJpegQuality` is working on HTC (Android `2.2.1`) and on Galaxy S2 (`4.1.2`), but fails on Galaxy S4 device (`4.2.2`).

So my question : Is this function deprecated ? Is there another way to set picture quality ? On the Developer documentation it doesnt seems to be a deprecated function so i am a little confused...

I also tried

```
params.set("jpeg-quality", jpegQuality);
```

But its the same :(

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Am I the 1st in the world to have issues with this function ?

Comment: I am probably the second one, but couldn't find a solution. Did you find one macTar?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with an S3.  setJpegQuality(80) seems to work fine on my Nexus 4 (4.4.4) and HTC Sensation (4.0.3), but on the S3 the photos seem to still be at full quality, resulting in 2X bigger file sizes.

Comment: any results on this one?

Comment: could you get the value of getJpegQuality(), and how do you know that the method doesn't work? please give more infor (logcat, debug dump value etc.)

Comment: The function doesn't appear to be deprecated, but you are possibly facing manufacturer implementation issues. If you haven't tried it yet, try stopping the preview before setting the quality then re-starting it. I have had issues in the past where the camera "driver" only reads parameters at startup.

Comment: had you've taken into account, that maybe the photo resolution is much bigger than on the other two?

Answer (score 1):

For S3 and S4, you can write device specific code to reduce the size of file.

If you search on google, Android dev team also mentioned that it all depends on the implementation by the manufacturer(https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8091). The implementation of the camera parameters and function totally depends on the hardware used I think.

I had used motion sensors for one of my apps. There also, I had to write device specific code, to get the required behaviour in the app.

I know its not what we expect as a developer, but i believe we, developers, can fix anything. :)

Answer (score 0):

I use the [CWAC-Camera](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) library for my custom camera.  I forked the main repository and added a `jpegQuality` parameter to the `PictureTransaction`:
https://github.com/cookbrite/cwac-camera/commit/65a0a2082194dfc8069f605f0191c43357bb0852

This ensures that the resulting picture is always compressed to the required quality.

One drawback with this approach is that it has to load and compress the full size image file in application code, whereas using `setJpegQuality` on the `Camera.Parameters` may be more optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didnt see answers finaly come :) I dont even use this not working parameters anymore

I found a solution to set the quality of my picture, when i save it as file :

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(finalFilePath);
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, jpegQuality, fos);
```

Hope it helps