# CWAC Camera - What's the best way to customize the ImageCleanupTask?

Tags: android, android-camera, commonsware-cwac, cwac-camera

I'm using the [cwac-camera](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) library to take photos with a custom in-app camera.

I'm overriding adjustPreviewParameters in SimpleCameraHost and am setting the JPEG quality.

```
@Override
public Parameters adjustPreviewParameters(Parameters parameters) {
    super.adjustPreviewParameters(parameters);
    parameters.setJpegQuality(80);
    return (parameters);
}
```

Unfortunately, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20420682/112705), the setJpegQuality method doesn't work on some devices (e.g. the S3).

I can see that the cwac-camera [ImageCleanupTask always saves the manipulated image at 100% JPEG quality](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/blob/master/camera/src/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/ImageCleanupTask.java#L141).

What's the best way to customize the ImageCleanupTask?

Should I expose a setJpegQuality method in [PictureTransaction](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/blob/master/camera/src/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/PictureTransaction.java)?  Or do we want a more versatile solution (like allowing the ImageCleanupTask to be injected)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can see that the cwac-camera ImageCleanupTask always saves the manipulated image at 100% JPEG quality.

Ideally, that would be configurable. There are lots of things the library would ideally do. :-)

> What's the best way to customize the ImageCleanupTask?

If you mean "how would one get the JPEG percentage in there?", augment `PictureTransaction`.

> Should I expose a setJpegQuality method in PictureTransaction?

I would do `jpegQuality()`, as `PictureTransaction` uses the builder/fluent API pattern.

Note that with this change, you would want to remove `parameters.setJpegQuality(80);` from your existing code. Otherwise, the image will be degraded twice, once on capture (for devices that support it) and once when the image is written to disk, and that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Here's the code change I made to support this in my fork: https://github.com/cookbrite/cwac-camera/commit/65a0a2082194dfc8069f605f0191c43357bb0852 Let me know if you want me to add an issue to your repo.  I can send a pull request too, although I may have subverted the jpegQuality field too much for you to want one. :-)

Comment: @DanJ: I went ahead and filed an [enhancement request](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/228) against myself. Your implementation seems fine off the cuff. Thanks!