# How to setJpegQuality(int i) Camera2API?

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

Please help me to understand how i can set `setJpegQuality(int i)` in my Camera2API?

I have surfed google and there are not a lot sample how to do it in CameraAPI, but there are any samples how to make it with Camera2API...

I have found [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setJpegQuality(int)) , but **maybe anyone know how to set it for Camera2API?**

Thanks!

Comment: Try this https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic

Comment: @sunilsunny i use this sample and it save picture in default quality 84... Question is how to pick this quality up?

Comment: Can You use this post to answer your question ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420682/android-camera-parameters-setjpegquality-deprecated-custom-camera-application

Comment: @Calixto no, because this question connect with CameraAPI, but my connect with Camera2API